# Spark, delta lake auto schema evolution for nested columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, delta-lake

what is the depth with which schema evolution works while merging?

Automatic schema evolution does not work while merging in the following case.

```
import json
d1 = {'a':'b','b':{'c':{'1':1}}}
d2 = {'a':'s','b':{'c':{'1':2,'2':2}}}
d3 = {'a':'v','b':{'c':{'1':4}}}

df1 = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json.dumps(d1)]))

#passes
df1.write.saveAsTable('test_table4',format='delta',mode='overwrite', path=f"hdfs://hdmaster:9000/dest/test_table4")


df2 = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json.dumps(d2)]))
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('updates')

query = """
MERGE INTO test_table4 existing_records 
        USING updates updates 
        ON existing_records.a=updates.a
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET * 
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"""
spark.sql("set spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled=true")
spark.sql(query) #passes



df3 = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json.dumps(d3)]))

df3.createOrReplaceTempView('updates')
query = """
MERGE INTO test_table4 existing_records 
        USING updates updates 
        ON existing_records.a=updates.a
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET * 
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"""
spark.sql("set spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled=true")
spark.sql(query) #FAILS #FAILS
```

This looks like failing when depth is more than 2 and incoming df has columns missing.
Is this intentionally like this?
This is handled perfectly with `option("mergeSchema", "true")` if want to append. But I want to UPSERT the data. But Merge is not able to handle this schema change

Using Delta Lake version 0.8.0

Answer (score 1):

In Delta 0.8, this should be regulated by setting `spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled` to `true`, in addition to the `mergeSchema` that is more for `append` mode.

See the [Delta 0.8 announcement blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/02/10/automatically-evolve-your-nested-column-schema-stream-from-a-delta-table-version-and-check-your-constraints.html) for more details of this feature.

Comment: Hey, I tried this. This does not work when you delete a field on a deeper level of a nested json

Comment: But deletion works when the field is deleted on root level as mentioned in the code shared